# Cannot publish my LUIS application

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I successfully created my Intents.

[image: screenshot from LUIS dashboard]

When intent has been created LUIS should allow publish application according to their documentation.

Why LUIS does not allow to publish my application?

Comment: Hi, your question is lacking detail, context and code. You might wanna have a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question in order to get more and better answers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read it and edited my post. :)

Comment: Your welcome. Usually you would paste your code into the question. Nobody wants to follow links or watch screenshots. That keeps people from answering. So, show the code, explain what you did, and show also the error message you get, the stack trace or whatever information helps others to help you.

Comment: This does not have code. It is about training bots using intends, entities and some other properties which helps bots works correctly.

Comment: @user7349079 Any success?

Comment: @user7349079 have you added any utterances into your LUIS model?  I have had the same problem in the past.

Answer (score 6):

The "Publish" option won't became available until you train your model for the first time. Click the "Train" button on the bottom of the page and the "Publish" button should became available. After you train your model for the first time LUIS will automatically train your model from time to time, but you still will be able to do it manually.